# FPS Test Issue with Onvif Test Tool v21.12 rev.7225

Tags: axis, frame-rate, onvif

When I test with v21.12 rev.7225,

Test items with issue:

1. RTSS-1-1-46-v21.12 VIDEO ENCODER CONFIGURATION - JPEG RESOLUTION
2. RTSS-1-1-48-v21.12 VIDEO ENCODER CONFIGURATION - H.264 RESOLUTION

Test camera:

1. AXIS P1375 with f/w 10.8.1, or 10.9.4 (It claims to pass v21.12)
2. IndigoVision BX620-4MP with f/w 2.2.0

Error Message:
"Only 0 frames captured (0.0 FPS)"

Note that we've tried increase Operation Delay, yet still fail the test items.

[image]

What we confuse:

1. We've tested numerous cameras with both OTT v21.06 and OTT v21.12.
2. With OTT v21.06, we passed both test items without issues.
   Yet with OTT v21.12, the fail rate is at around 80% as we tested several times with each cameras.
   All setups are exactly the same, except the OTT version.
   It's also quite weird to us that not every time we test with OTT v21.12 result fail.

We'd like to know if there's any change on test procedure or criteria for both test items to help us solve the issues.

Comment: How is this related to C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good news,
v22.06 already fix this problem written on ONVIF_Device_Test_Tool_Errata v3.51.pdf,
Erratum number: 60

[image]

share with everyone

BR,

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem and found that the new version updated the UDP port used to obtain the URL stream is fixed

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31609315)

Answer (score 0):

So nice
We had the same problem and we were looking

https://github.com/onvif/testspecs/discussions/21
If you check the link above, this is an ONVIF Test Tool bug
Maybe it will be fixed in v22.06! Hope this helps!

And check the ONVIF_Device_Test_Tool_Errata v3.50 file!
You can get that file at onvif.org

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to remember two things about the ONVIF conformance (none of those are related to programming):

- Each ONVIF compliant camera published on https://www.onvif.org/conformant-products/ has an Interface Guide that explains if special settings are required before starting the test.
- To be ONVIF conformant, cameras must have one FW tested with the testtool that was valid at the time of the certification. There is no requirement to re-certify the FW once newer versions of the test tool are released. Therefore it may happen that they pass with 21.06 and not with 21.12

Comment: Hi I using the software 10.9.4 that claims to pass v21.12 to test will still cause problems

Comment: I Provide the wireshark of axis camera, at packet 751 start to "DESCRIBE"
https://www.sendspace.com/file/mfj6na

Comment: The issue described in the question is true. I am seeing it on other cameras too. it is definitely a ONVIF Device test tool issue with 21.12

Comment: On 16 Feb 2022, ONVIF recognized this usse and gave erratum number 60. You can refer to this erratum when generating the DoC, it will still be accepted. You can find more info about this erratum in the ONVIF member portal.